# Get all elements value of List<x, y>

Tags: c#, .net, list, loops

I'm new here and I would like some help with List ...

Actually, I want to add every `y` elements of my `List<x, y>` to a variable. I know, it's probably very easy but I'm stuck on that part ..

```
/// <summary>
/// Number of cards in the deck
/// </summary>
public byte NbTotalCards
{
    get
    {
        byte nbCards = 0;

        for (byte i = 0; i <= this.LstCardsWithQt.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.LstCardsWithQt[i].Qt != 0)
            {
                if(this.LstCardsWithQt[i].Qt.Equals(2))
                    nbCards += 2;
                else
                {
                    nbCards += 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nbCards += 0;
            }
        }
        return nbCardss;
    }
}
```

Where

`public List<DeckEntry> LstCardsWithQt`

and

```
public DeckEntry(Card card, byte qt)
{
    this.Card = carte;
    this.Qt = qt;
}
```

btw, I get an error on `this.LstCardsWithQt[i].Qt != 0`

> ArgumentOutOfRangeExeption("Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection")

Comment: In the for loop, you should change <= to <, because it has only Count elements.

Comment: Are you sure you only want to increment `nbCards` by 1 if an item's `Qt` is 3 or more? And why that `nbCards += 0;` line? It doesn't do anything useful. And why use `Equals` to compare bytes instead of `==`?

Comment: Not a List<x, y>.   List <DeckEntry>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looping through your collection in a wrong way. Instead of

```
for (byte i = 0; i <= this.LstCardsWithQt.Count; i++)
```

it has to be

```
for (byte i = 0; i < this.LstCardsWithQt.Count; i++)
```

(you can also drop the "this" qualifier, this seems like Java Code)

New approach: If you just want to sum up the property `card.Qt` of all your cards you can do

```
public int NbTotalCards
{
    get
    { 
         return LstCardsWithQt.Sum( card => card.Qt);
    }
}
```

(proveded that `card.Qt` has only values between 0 and 2 and it's still the same logic- I allowed myself to change the type of sum to `int` instead of a `byte`. You also need `using System.Linq` at the beginning of your file if you do that.)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was just about to write this and then saw this answer.